# Bash script unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

I have the following code:

```
   #!/bin/bash -x

   # Arguments:

   #    $1 - command to run

   # $2 - time limit (in milliseconds)

   # $3 - memory limit (in kilobytes)

   # NOTE TO SELF: $! is the pid of last process

   # NOTE TO SELF: Appending & creates new process

   dir=$(mktemp -d)

   ulimit -m $3

   { $1 ; "$?" > "$dir/retc" } &

   pid=$!

   ./sleep.pl $2

   if [ ps -p $pid > /dev/null ]

   then

     kill -9 $pid

     echo "0Time Limit Exceeded"

   else

     echo "NAH"

     ret=$(cat "$dir/retc")

     if [ $ret = 9 ]

     then

       echo "0Memory Limit Exceeded"

     else

       if [ $ret = 0 ]

       then

         echo "1" # If it only returns one then it must be passed through final phase of verifying if result is correct

       else

         echo "0Received signal $ret"

       fi

     fi

   fi

   rm -r $dir

   exit 0
```

However, it returns an error "Unexpected end of file", without executing anything in the if/else blocks.

Comment: How do you execute the file? (Which arguments?)

Comment: $ bash ./limiter.sh main 1000 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the semicolon, the redirection is wrong also:

```
{ $1 ; "$?"; } >"$dir/retc" &
```

From bash man: list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon

Also:

```
if [ ps -p $pid > /dev/null ]
```

Should be:

```
if [[ $(ps -p $pid >/dev/null) -eq 0 ]]
```

Comment: Using a semicolon is correct. However I think what he wanted was `{ "$1"; echo "$?" > "$dir/retc"; } &`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `()` over `{}` to explicitly show that you're wanting to summon a subshell. Also I think you missed `echo` to show the value of `$?`.

```
( "$1"; echo "$?" > "$dir/etc"; ) &
```

With `()` you wouldn't need to add a semicolon in the end unlike with `{}` however it's still a good practice.